# Stop actor message processing on timeout

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

I am using the ask pattern with a timeout to send a message to my actor, which might take a long time to process it. I would like to stop processing the message if the timeout expires. But, it seems the actor keeps processing the message, and I receive a dead letter.

How can I stop the actor from processing the message when the timeout expires?

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is that you can't.  Once it starts processing it, sending Kill or Poison Pill or stopping it will only prevent it from processing future messages.  The long answer is that maybe you can hack around this if the actor happened to be in a loop of some sort and was checking some mutable (and potentially globally available) signal for stopping looping, but there are so many red flags with that approach that you should forget I even mentioned it.  And if the long call happened to be a blocking io call to something like a DB, forget about it; you're stuck until that call completes (or times out if you are lucky).

The actor itself is not aware that someone called it via `ask` and there is a `Future` upstream that might time out.  It has no concept of this and thus can not react accordingly when that `Future` times out.

Comment: Yeah, the long call is actually a blocking call to a db. I guess I could wrap the db call in another `Future` with a timeout, and handle a timeout exception.

Comment: @vh4x0r, that's probably a good idea.  You should also consider wrapping the code in the `Future` in a `blocking` block so the execution context knows it's a blocking call and handle it appropriately.  Also, you might want to use a separate `ExecutionContext` for these blocking IO calls so that a backup there won't have adverse effects on the main dispatcher for your Akka system.